# Is this dividing wall load bearing?

Tags: walls, removal, load

My fiancée and I are remodeling our recently purchased home and want to triple check to confirm this is not a load bearing wall before tearing it down.

The portion of the wall touching the ceiling is 2’ 10” in length, and is 4” wide. There is nothing supporting the wall in the crawl space, and in the attic the joists do not stop at the wall. We believe it is not load bearing. Is there anything else we could be overlooking? Could it be load bearing?

Please let me know if any other details would help. Photos here:

[image: Wall in question]

[image: Attic view]